# Vue Cli 3 project won't generate manifest.json (PWA)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli-3

I have a Vue Cli 3 project with `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` plugin installed and configured (in `vue.config.js`), but when I run `vue-cli-service build --modern` no `manifest.json` is generated based on my config.

I'm expecting to see a `manifest.json` that would contain, at the very least, the paths of the icons I specified. Maybe also the settings that I put in the `vue.config.js`.

Am I doing something wrong or maybe my expectation of how the plugin should work doesn't match the actual behavior?

How am I supposed to make Vue generate my `manifest.json`?

Comment: Did you choose _ PWA support_ option while initialing the app with `vue create <app-name>` ?

Comment: @AdamOrlov I'm almost sure I did, but is there a way I can check?

Comment: Well I'd say there should be an info in your package.json. Any way besides manifest.json also `registerServiceWorker.js` file should be created. Do you have it?

Comment: Yes, I do have the `registerServiceWorker.js`. I also checked the Vue UI, and it states that PWA component is enabled, which means that the project supports PWA. So, why Vue isn't generating the manifest.json?

Comment: The file should be located in `public` folder. Did you check there?

Comment: Yes, but there is no such file in that folder (nor any other folder, believe me, I looked a thousand times).

Comment: I see,... hmm  Can you update Vue CLI 3 to the newest version and create a new project on a side? Just to check if a new project will create manifest.json?

Comment: I created a new project, selected manual config, then enabled PWA. I did saw a file called `manifest.json` in the public folder of the newly generated project. But then I edited the `pwa` section of the `vue.config.js` file and changed the name of the app, and ran `yarn vue build`. The result (in the `dist` folder) contained a `manifest.json` file, but it had the "old" project name instead of the one that I typed in the `vue.config.js`. Which means that the build process just blindly copies whatever there is in the `public` folder (including the `manifest.json` file) instead of generating it.

Comment:  Man I can't think of anything more. I would post an issue on [github PWA plugin:]("https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues") maybe there someone wille have better knowledge 

Comment: found this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3383 - seems status of manifest.json is not clear! IMO it should be generated, but is not...

Comment: Having the same issue. Generated a new project with latest CLI. No `manifest.json`. I do have the service worker so `PWA` was enabled.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I ran a production build: `yarn build` or `npm build` and found the `manifest.json` file in the `dist` folder.

Comment: Same issue. So if we need to change manifest.json, we do directly in the dist folder?

Comment: @Coisox My app is working being the `manifest.json` in the *dist* folder, so I guess that's the correct location now

Answer (score 0):

try Adding manifest.json manually under public file or you can also copy the manifest.json generated after npm build under the dist folder into the public file and then edit it according to your needs. Also check if your browser is detecting the manifest.json or not.

Comment: if you go through the official doc you cannot access manifest.json in development mode. If you wish to change the configuration, it is handled via the PWA property in vue.config.js file. You can refer to https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html#configuration the doc

Answer (score 0):

`manifest.json` is generated each time you build your project, it shouldn't be modified directly or added in `public` dir.

Instead, in order to update `manifest.json`, you should modify `vue.config.js` and add pertinent data under `pwa` key.

```
// vue.config.js
const {defineConfig} = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  pwa: {
    name: 'My nice pwa app',
    short_name: 'Nice',
    theme_color: "#4DBA87",
    icons: [
      {
        src: "./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
        sizes: "192x192",
        type: "image/png"
      }
      // etc ...
    ]
    // etc ...
  }
})
```

Source: https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html#configuration