# How do I change the appname of a Vue PWA app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, vue-cli-3

I'm using `vue-cli` version 3.11.0 to build my web app along with the `pwa` plugin. I'd like to change the appname (the one that shows up when adding to homescreen). How do I do so? I don't see any `manifest.json` file anywhere in the project.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53463944/2873538) post help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa`, check [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html#example-configuration).

```js
// vue.config.js in your project (IF NOT EXIST, create new one)
module.exports = {
  // ...other vue-cli plugin options...
  pwa: {
    name: 'My App', // <---- this is PWA name
  }
}
```